# Can I control request timeouts within Azure Storage Retry Policies?

Tags: c#, azure-storage-queues

It took me some time to understand the idea behind the RetryPolicies the Azure Storage SDK (and probably otehr SDKs as well) provides.

For Microsoft documentation see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/retry-service-specific#azure-storage-retry-guidelines

Consider the following code:

```
// [...] get storage, queueclient, queue, ...
CloudQueueMessage message = new CloudQueueMessage ("sample");

OperationContext operationContext = new OperationContext();
operationContext.SendingRequest += (sender, eventArgs) => {
    Console.WriteLine(">> {0}: SendingRequest...", DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff tt"));
};

operationContext.Retrying += (sender, eventArgs) => {
    Console.WriteLine(">> {0}: Retrying...", DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff tt"));
};

operationContext.RequestCompleted += (sender, eventArgs) => {
    Console.WriteLine(">> {0}: RequestCompleted (took: {1}).",
        DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff tt"),
        (eventArgs.RequestInformation.EndTime - eventArgs.RequestInformation.StartTime).TotalMilliseconds);
};

operationContext.ResponseReceived += (sender, eventArgs) => {
    Console.WriteLine(">> {0}: ResponseReceived...", DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff tt"));
};

QueueRequestOptions queueRequestOptions = new QueueRequestOptions
{
    // RETRY POLICY
    RetryPolicy = new LinearRetry(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000), 3),
    MaximumExecutionTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40)
};

try
{
    await queue.AddMessageAsync(message, TimeSpan.FromDays(7), TimeSpan.Zero, queueRequestOptions, operationContext);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("EXCEPTION: " + ex.Message);
    return false;
}
```

**Test Setup**
- I set a local DNS entry to redirect request to messagebox.queue.core.windows.net to a local IP address (which is not responding) in order to simulate connection timeouts.

**Observations:**

> 06:13:01.952 : SendingRequest...
>   06:13:23.036 : RequestCompleted (took: 21083,6253).
>   06:13:25.040 : Retrying...
>   06:13:25.040 : SendingRequest...
>   06:13:41.908 : RequestCompleted (took: 16867,7884).
>   EXCEPTION: The client could not finish the operation within specified timeout.

- The `MaximumExecutionTime` is a hard time cap in which the client has to sucessfully deliver its message
- But why is there only one retry? And why did the request take so long?

The RetryPolicy defines the **backing off time**.
Looking at the timestamps above you see that the retry ~2000ms after the initial request failed. That's exactly the 2000ms I defined in the RetryPolicy earlier.

What I can unfortunately NOT control is **how long a client is trying to deliver its message**. If the `MaximumExecutionTime` is not specified it defaults to 120s.

**Results after removing the `MaximumExecutionTime` property**:

> 06:21:21.681 : SendingRequest...
>   06:21:42.752 : RequestCompleted (took: 21071,3961).
>   06:21:44.762 : Retrying...
>   06:21:44.762 : SendingRequest...
>   06:22:26.820 : RequestCompleted (took: 42057,7503).
>   06:22:28.835 : Retrying...
>   06:22:28.835 : SendingRequest...
>   06:23:10.868 : RequestCompleted (took: 42033,8183).
>   06:23:12.886 : Retrying...
>   06:23:12.886 : SendingRequest...
>   06:23:54.928 : RequestCompleted (took: 42042,4322).
>   EXCEPTION: An error occurred while sending the request.

**Here are my questions about this...**

- Ok, so why is the timeout value for the first request ~20s and for all subsequent requests ~40s?
- Can I control this? I want requests to fail much faster than 20 oder even 40 seconds!

As a "workaround" I set the `MaximumExecutionTime` to 500ms.
I set the retry policy to `NoRetry`.
I am using Polly to handle retries.